# Как расширить selectableItemBackground для TableRow с ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть **TableLayout** c **TableRow**, в котором лежат элементы **ImageView** и **TextView**. Я сделал их отдельно кликабельными. При нажатии на элемент с **TextView** - **Background** подсвечивается полностью, если нажимать на элемент с **ImageView** - подсвечивается только иконка и маленькие углы. Как мне сделать, что бы выделялась полностью вся **layout_column** с элементом ImageView.
Спасибо!

Вот мой TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgForList"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textForList"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#fffbffbe"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgForMyList"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я переделал **layout**, заменил **TableLayout** на **RelativeLayout** и сделал **padding** для картинок:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgForList"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textForList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textForList"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textForList"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textForList"
    android:layout_width="262dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#fffbffbe"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgForMyList"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textForList"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textForList"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textForList"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```